# Taking a screenshot of streaming content in webView (eg Youtube video)

Tags: android, stream, screenshot

I am working on an app which should save the displayed content of a webview. The problem is that when the webview displays streamed content (like a YouTube video) the screenshot returns just a black rectangle - as there is no actual image. If I take a screenshot with volume & power button the screenshot does contain the actual frame of the video, which would be exactly what I need. Unfortunately this stops my app for a moment, as the screenshot creates a new overlay. I have already created two questions on SO, none of the solutions worked so far:

[Take a screenshot of a video in a webview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182503/take-a-screenshot-of-a-video-in-a-webview-android)

[Android - capture exactly what the screen displays (video/stream) - save it as image on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31262513/android-capture-exactly-what-the-screen-displays-video-stream-save-it-as-i)

Comment: did you tried this answer given by me ? it is similar problem as i faced earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081880/converting-web-view-as-image-in-android-4-4-web-view-not-working/28082386#28082386

Comment: You set a .png as the background of the webview? All my pngs have been black so far.. The webview does display what I want, just the screenshots are all black :(

Comment: did you tried as i tried in my question & with the webview properties ?